# Dark activity dialog theme not working

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-theme

I want to have a dark activity dialog theme, so I define following:

```
<style name="AppThemeDialogActivityDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- dark toolbar + dark popup menu -->
    <item name="toolbarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>


    <!-- trying to forcefully set the background and text color -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>

    <item name="android:minWidth">320dp</item>

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Activity:

```
public class FeedbackActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // darkTheme returns true!!!
        setTheme(MainApp.getPrefs().darkTheme() ? R.style.AppThemeDialogActivityDark : R.style.AppThemeDialogActivity);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_feedback);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:theme="?toolbarTheme"/>

        <ListView
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/lvFeedback"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/svFeedback"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tvFeedback"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/btButton"
            style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

What am I missing here? Why does my activity dialog have a white background instead of the dark one???

**EDIT - Interesting details**

- Setting the views backgrounds to `android:background="?android:windowBackground"` does work. But I have to do this for the ListView and for the TextView. That this theme attribute works means, the theme is applied correctly, seems like the default background is defined in another theme attribute in a dialog theme?
- my `ListView` items are themed correctly as well by simply using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` as layout, I don't need to set their background/text colors, they are correctly themed for a dark theme, but not visible if I don't set the `ListView` background manually like above

Comment: You should check your values-vxx folder and see the style files in them. maybe for some of them the style is different from what you need. Also you should check your layout file and see if they are using any specified style from your styles file or not.

Comment: that's a good idea, but I'm quite lazy creating special styles for different screen sizes and checked this now and this is not the case

Comment: And I added my xml layout, I'm not setting any background color manually in there... And I'm not setting any color in code, the activity is a very simple activity with a few lines of code only

Comment: Maybe this condition fails and fallback on using `AppTheneDialogActivity`: `setTheme(MainApp.getPrefs().darkTheme() ? R.style.AppThemeDialogActivityDark : R.style.AppThemeDialogActivity);`. Have you checked it?

Comment: Checked this, it does not fail for sure. Even removed it and used `setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDialogActivityDark)` and made a clean build, no difference, I still get a white background

Comment: I don't know why this is necessary, but setting the views backgrounds to `android:background="?android:windowBackground"` does work. But I have to do this for the `ListView` and for the `TextView`. That this theme attribute works means, the theme is applied correctly, seems like the default background is defined in another theme attribute in a dialog theme?

Comment: check if you have applied the theme in manifest.xml

Comment: @randy I've set the light theme there by default, I'm overwriting this default value in code though as shown in my code above. Dark or light theme is a user setting in my app...

Comment: okay . Try to use `setTheme` after super() . Also i cant see setcontentview in the code.

Comment: `setTheme` must be called before super and the `setContentView` is called afterwards. I'm using this a lot in my activities, I only have problems with the dialog theme

Answer (score 1):

Try to change parent
 `parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Dialog.Alert"`